# Need a help in the proof that certain infinite matrices give rise to bounded linear operators on $l_{2}.$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, proof-explanation

The proof is given in the following pictures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

But I do not understand why the last paragraph is true, could anyone explain this for me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This proof gives a sufficient condition, but not a necessary condition. See  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessity_and_sufficiency for definitions if you are unfamiliar with these terms in logic and mathematics.

In essence, this page states that

$$\text{Condition (1)} \implies A \text{ is bounded}$$

but notes in the last paragraph that the converse is not true

$$A \text{ is bounded} \not \Rightarrow \text{Condition (1)}$$

by giving an explicit counter-example. It then remarks that there are no known conditions on the entries of $A$ that make this work, i.e., we don't know of an uber-condition such that

$$ \text{Statement about the matrix entries } a_{ij} \iff A \text{is bounded}.$$

In effect, the very last paragraph is true because$\dots$nobody has been able come up with one, or at least not that the author is aware of.